# Using facebook php library, specifying "publish_stream" in the scope parameter, does not give me publishing rights

Tags: php, facebook, facebook-graph-api

I have two websites with apps setup for them. When I click the login link (generated by the code below) on the first site it will bring up the

"APP will receive the following info: your public profile, friend list and email address."

then when I click okay on that it brings up the dialog that says

"APP would like to post to Facebook for you."

However, on my other site the second dialog never appears, and of course I don't have permission to post on the users behalf. Does anyone have any ideas what could be wrong?

I am using the facebook php SDK

```
function __construct()
{

    $this->connection = new Facebook(array(
        'appId' => FACEBOOK_APP_ID,
        'secret' => FACEBOOK_SECRET,
        'allowSignedRequest' => true
    ));
    parent::__construct();
}

public function getLoginUrl($callback_url = '')
{
   $params = array('scope'=>'email,publish_stream');
    if($callback_url){
        $params['redirect_uri'] = $callback_url;
    }
    if(!$this->getUser()){
        return $this->connection->getLoginUrl($params);
    }
    return false;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Facebook introduced new permission called "publish_actions" instead of public_stream.You can see the reference [here](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/facebook-login/permissions/v2.0)

Comment: I'm using the Facebook SDK v3.2.3, should "publish_actions" be a drop-in replacement for publish_stream? From what I've read so far I should just be able to replace one with the other in my scope parameter, but that doesn't work for me at all.

Answer (score 0):

If you're using Graph API v2.0, the `publish_stream` permission has been replaced by `publish_actions`, see the Permissions references under

https://developers.facebook.com/docs/facebook-login/permissions/v2.0#reference-extended-publish

Comment: I'm using the php SDK v3.2.3, is there an easy way for me to figure out which version of the Graph API I'm using?

Comment: @Moistorious - This is waaay late, but one way to check is to take the auth token that your app acquires for the user (after authentication) and run it through FB's [Access Token Debugger](https://developers.facebook.com/tools/debug/access_token/)